# AES Sbox with alternative polynomial

Tags: aes

I've used the C++ prog I found on the web to generate the standard Sbox with poly 0x11b, and also modified it to use a lookup table of all the multiplicative inverses of the 256 values, which also works fine.  I'm now trying to generate alternative Sbox using polynomial 0x11d, as used in the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.protcy.2013.12.443) by Das, Zaman & Ghosh, but without much success.  I've again generated all the multiplicative inverses for the poly and used them in a lookup table, but I do not get the same results as the paper's authors.

Comment: I added a link to a paper that seems to be refereed to in the question. I guess that the results not replicated are those in Appendix A. To the OP: welcome to CSE. Don't attach your C++ prog: describe what it does and how, and illustrate that with the intermediary steps producing an example value that does not match; like, the first discrepancy w.r.t. Table A1(a). There is a good chance you will solve your problem in this way. And if you do not, someone likely will. Unrelated: the interest of what this paper does is dubious at best, and some of it (section 3 and its table 1) is nonsense.

Comment: I generated all the inverses for the polynomial 0x11d, my first error against the paper was for the value 0x03, which I have inverse of 0xf4, (which I manually checked ok in the GF)  The affine transform of this gives me 0x26, adding the fixed offset vector 0x0a i get the result 0x2c,  the paper has 0x90.  Is the paper wrong, or is it me?

Comment: Sorry, but to me the paper you cited looks like rubbish (not your fault!!). The purpose of the paper seems to add a publication to their list. I hope none of the authors is your advisor, and that you don't have an advisor recommending you to read such stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.protcy.2013.12.443)'s tables in Appendix A are wrong.

For the entries in the first line of Table A1(a) I independently get:

```
0A 15 3F 2C 90 3B 19 51 FD EF 28 8C 83 A0 A7 36
```

and the fourth value (for input 03<sub>h</sub>) matches the [OP's computation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/168457).

Note: there are fixed points (including 23<sub>h</sub>), invalidating the *list of the valid additive constants*, which is about the only attempt at an addition to self-citation [15] (at least, Appendix 1 table 2b appears correct and is available for free [there](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-81-322-1665-0_29)).

Recommendation: if working on that paper is an assignment in a crypto course, question the competence or/and honesty of the assigner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply "fgrieu", I agree with your first 16 values, presumably the whole 256 values.  I guess the paper I came across is rubbish, (I also spotted that 23 mapped to 23).  I was only doing this for my own edification, as a retired electronic engineer where I used AES in systems quite bit, just thought I'd see what options there were for (maybe) improving security, as obviously the standard S-box is widely known.